# xcopy not going to goto

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to write a batch file to copy a directory to another. However, if the destination directory exist, the batch should end and goto the error handler. However, on running, it seems that the xcopy code is always running. Any help is appreciated.

```
@echo off
::Ask
echo Your Source Path:
set INPUT1=
set /P INPUT1=Type Source Path: %=%

echo Your Destination Path:
set INPUT2=
set /P INPUT2=Type Destination Path: %=%

if NOT EXIST INPUT2 (xcopy %INPUT1% %INPUT2% /s) else (goto errorHandler)


:errorHandler
echo Directory Exists, Please Check
pause
```

Comment: Should it be `if NOT EXIST %INPUT2%` ? BTW, you need one more `goto` to skip `Directory Exists` message after xcopy execution.

Comment: @AlexFarber certainly should be - but "quoted" to ensure correct handling of names containing spaces. I'm also puzzled by the obsession with double-negatives. `if EXIST "%INPUT2%" goto errorhandler` [new line] `xcopy "%INPUT1%" "%INPUT2%\" /s` would be my preference - since the destination doesn't exist, have `xcopy` create it.

Comment: @AlexFarber thanks for answering, mistake on my side